# Set print view for word document 2013

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have an MS word add in based on MSWord 2010. With this add in I can open a model file (*.dotx) which fills out all the placeholder. It works fine for 2010. But if I try opening a file in MSWord 2013 it opens in reading mode. But I want it to open in print view. I tried to set the view to `wdPrintView` but it didn't help. What I tried is this:

```
using word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

word.Application app = new word.Application();
word.Document doc = app.Documents.Add(this.Name);

doc.ActiveWindow.View.Type = word.WdViewType.wdPrintView;
```

Does anyone know why it still opens in "reading mode"?

Suggestions appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. But its not in C#. You have to go to your Word 2013 settings. Go to `Options > General`. Uncheck the checkbox `Open e-mail attachments and other uneditable files in reading view`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you get both the document and the printview. 
You can add the following line, so it won't show the word document:

- app.Visible = False;

(If this is what you mean.)

Comment: What I mean is that the document opens in wrong view. Normally if you open a word document you can edit it and. But if I open it with this add in it opens in "Read Mode". If you open Word 2013 and go to tab "View" -> "Read Mode" you'll see how my document opens. Hope you know what I mean :)